# Can't figure out how to use Linq to XML to do conditional adding of Nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to use Linq to XML to create a file from a list of employees that also have a list of groups they are associated with. However, I have to do some conditional checking with those groups as well. I’ve got some code that will create the employees but I don’t know how to loop through the groups and conditionally add elements.

Here is the example of how the XML is supposed to be formatted. They want one node per employee with multiple attributes. Then a node under the employee for each group they are associated with. That’s the part I’m having the issue with.

```
<CXIXML>
  <Directives>
    <Updates>
      <Emp tasEmpID="00123" lName="Doe" fName="John" empStatus="A" classification="S" />
      <Group groupId="1">
      <Group groupId="5">
      <Group groupId="12">
      <Emp tasEmpID="00456" lName="Smith" fName="Jane" empStatus="A" classification="S" />
      <Group groupId="1">
    </Updates>
  </Directives>
</CXIXML>
```

Below is how I’m currently using Linq to XML to create the employee file. That’s working and my initial thought is to create the employee XML file and then loop back through the employee list, find the employee node based on the ID in the attribute, look up which group they are in, then add the group node.

I feel like there has to be an easier way to do this especially since I have the employees I need to create in addition to the fact that each employee object already has they groups they are associated with in the ClockGroup list.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string AdminEnrollFlag { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeLastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeWorkStat { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCo { get; set; }

    public List<GroupAssociation> ClockGroup { get; set; }
}

public class GroupAssociation
{
    public int emp_id { get; set; }
    public int group_id { get; set; }
}


private static void CreateExportFile(List<Employee> fileEmployees, string fileCount)
{
    string fileLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileLocation"];

    XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XElement("CXIXML",
            new XElement("Directives",
            new XElement("Updates",
                from emp in fileEmployees
                select new XElement("Emp",
                                    new XAttribute("tasEmpID", emp.EmployeeId.PadLeft(8, '0')),
                                    new XAttribute("lName", emp.EmployeeLastName),
                                    new XAttribute("fName", emp.EmployeeFirstName),                                 
                                    new XAttribute("empStatus", SetWorkStat(emp.EmployeeWorkStat)),
                                    new XAttribute("classification", SetClassification(emp.AdminWebAccess, emp.AdminEnrollFlag))))))
    );


    string formatedDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm_");
    string filePath = fileLocation + "VTC_" + formatedDate + fileCount.PadLeft(3, '0') + ".xml";
    xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
}


<CXIXML>
  <Directives>
    <Updates>
      <Emp tasEmpID="00123" lName="Doe" fName="John" empStatus="A" classification="S" />
      <Emp tasEmpID="00456" lName="Smith" fName="Jane" empStatus="A" classification="S" />
    </Updates>
  </Directives>
</CXIXML>
```

So, here is the kicker with groups. I have some conditions to look at for the groups. If there 0 group associations I have to write out a node where the groupId is a specific number (ex: GroupId=2 for no group association). I also have to look to see if they have Admin access and if so they have a specific groupId (ex: GroupId=1) otherwise I have to write out all the groups.

Do you think this can all be done with Linq to XML? Or, should I use XmlDocument write out nodes based on my List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` in a very similar way to `XmlDocument`, so you certainly don't need to change that.

I'd probably do something like this:

```
var employeeUpdates = fileEmployees.SelectMany(CreateEmployeeElements);

XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("CXIXML",
        new XElement("Directives",
            new XElement("Updates", employeeUpdates)
        )
    )
);
```

And `CreateEmployeeElements` can return as many elements as it likes per employee (I've left out most of the detail):

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> CreateEmployeeElements(Employee employee)
{
    yield return new XElement("Emp", /* content */);

    if (employee.ClockGroup.Count == 0)
    {
        yield return new XElement("Group", new XAttribute("groupId", 2));
    }

    // and so on for more element conditions
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed. Thanks!